# why my table of contents appear in horizontal list

Tags: table-of-contents

this is how I write:

```
\documentclass[twoside,tocchapterhead]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[hmarginratio=2:3]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
%\usepackage[top=1.2in, bottom=1.2in, right=1.2in, left=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inner=1.5in,outer=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\myint}{\int_0^\infty}
\newenvironment{proof}{{\scshape Proof. }\itshape }
{\hfill$\spadesuit$\par}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Title}
\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{CERTIFICATION}}
\include{Certification}
\begin{center}
    {\bf CERTIFICATION OF SUPERVISOR}
    ...
\end{center}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ABSTRACT}}
\include{Abstract}
\begin{center}
    {\bf Abstract
    ...}
\end{center}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ABSTRAK}}
\include{Abstrak}
\begin{center}
    {\bf Abstrak
    ...}
\end{center}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}}
\include{Acknow}
\begin{center}
    {\normalsize \bf ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\end{center}
...

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

And this is how they appear
[image]

why they are appearing in the horizontal list not vertical?

Comment: look in the `.toc` file you are just writing the bold words with no formatting.

Comment: Welcoe to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not writing `\chapter{Certification}` in your tex file?

Comment: Agree with @Teepeemm seems you're using something similar to `\frontmatter` already. BTW: please make a full but minimal example instead of a snitplet like this where we have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Hmm, I can recreate this if I use the `article` class which **does not support chapter!!**

Comment: i just edited my question

Comment: That is not a good edit, we still cannot see which class you are using, plus we do not have access to the included files (they are not relevant for the issue anyway)

Comment: okay after some reading I found out that the problem is class `article` does not support `\chapter`. so I change it to `report` and its working now.

Comment: And now you know why we always ask for a full but minimal example. We could have solved this an hour ago if you provided the proper information to start with.

Comment: Unrelated: there is no need to load `amsfonts` as it is loaded automatically by `amssymb`

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm new to this so

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that a solution of your problem ?

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\chapter{\textbf{CERTIFICATION}}

\chapter{\textbf{ABSTRACT}}

\chapter{\textbf{ABSTRAK}}

\chapter{\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I would recommend not having `\textbf` in the chapter command, and probably not putting the chapter title in all caps.  If you're wanting that styling, there are packages that can help achieve that (notably titlesec).